# How to use a ruby variable as the default value in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Good sirs:

I have this

```
 <%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :value => '<%= @user.name %>' } %>
```

and the erb tags within erb tags brings joy to no one.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just remove the erb tags?

```
<%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :value => @user.name } %>
```

Comment: Cuz that gives me the literal text instead go the value

Answer (score 1):

Use it as `value: @user.name`:

```
<%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :value => @user.name } %>
```

If the form builder object `f` in your case is for the `@user` instance then the value will be pre-populated in case of validation errors.  For example, the following will suffice:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The form is not for user which is why I have to force the attributes from user as defaults.